# Unable to pass R variable values to Redis using RREDIS PACKAGE

Tags: r, redis, neural-network

I am using the RRDEDIS package as a client to REDIS. I am building a **neural-redis module**.

I am performing all pre-processing of data in R and I am sending the variables from R to the REDIS instance using **RedisCmd** command. I am using the iris dataset.

When I pass it as values, the modules accepts the input. If I pass the variables, then it says its an invalid neural network input.

```
   NR.OBSERVE works if the values are given individually

   library(rredis)
   redisConnect("localhost",6379)
   create <- redisCmd('NR.CREATE','net', 'REGRESSOR', '2','3', '->', '1','NORMALIZE','DATASET','50','TEST','10')
   obs<- redisCmd('NR.OBSERVE', 'net','1','2','->','3')
```

**NR.OBSERVE however does not work if I give a variable containing the values.**

```
   library(rredis)
   redisConnect("localhost",6379)
   create <- redisCmd('NR.CREATE','net', 'REGRESSOR', '2','3', '->', '1','NORMALIZE','DATASET','50','TEST','10')
    a<-1
    b<-2
    c<-3
   obs<- redisCmd('NR.OBSERVE', 'net','a','b','->','c')
```

This throws the following error

> **Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
>     ERR invalid neural network input: must be a valid float precision floating point number**
>
> **What is the correct way of doing it**

Comment: Why are you quoting them? I mean I see you are quoting the numbers but in this case you are quoting letters and they are just letters not objects.  I think you need to figure out that. Maybe get the values back? maybe `a<-'1'  ` etc and then don't quote in the reddisCmd call

Comment: @Elin - Thank you so very much. It worked ..